# why destructor id printing message again in python?

Tags: python

here is my code

```
class third:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Cons is called")

    def __del__(self):
        print("desc is called")

    def setName(self,firstName,lastName):
        self.firstName=firstName;
        self.lastName=lastName;

    def displayName(self):
        print(self.firstName,' ' ,self.lastName)

ob=third(); 
ob.setName('gaurav','sharma');
ob.displayName()
ob.__del__()
ob.displayName();
```

and output is

```
  Cons is called
  gaurav   sharma  
  desc is called
  gaurav   sharma
  desc is called
```

i have destroyed object by using del and then tried to call displayname function again still it is providing distroyed values and now i m confused weather the object is destroid or not.

Comment: `__del__` is like any other method, when called directly.

Comment: `__del__()` is called by each destruction of instance. Calling of `__del__()` doesn't destroy the object self

Comment: Note that having setters and getters is not Pythonic - use `@property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `__del__()` directly as it will only run that method but won't actually delete the object. Use the `del` statement to delete an object:

```
>>> del ob
>>> ob
>>> NameError: name 'ob' is not defined
```

Comment: `del` is not a function, so no parentheses please.

Comment: @Daniel You are right, fixed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @deniel it's working.